# Integrating Boost.Asio in GUI

Tags: c++, multithreading, user-interface, asynchronous, boost-asio

I have a simple code that is using boost.asio like the following one:

```
namespace net = boost::asio;
int main()
{
    net::io_context ioContext;
    AsyncClass myClass(ioContext);

    myClass.onAsyncEvent1([] { /* do stuff */ })
    myClass.onAsyncEvent2([] { /* do stuff */ });

    ioContext.run();
    return 0;
}
```

I want now to add this code in a GUI application (Android/Linux/Windows).

The solutions I found on the network are very inefficient for me. The most common are:

1. have a GUI timer and call from there the `poll_one` function.
2. Use polling:

   1. Check if a message from the GUI and process it if any
   2. call `poll_one`
   3. sleep sum

But these two solution are just keeping the CPU high for doing nothing, and on a mobile phone, it just means wasting buttery.

**WHAT I WANT**

I would like to block everything until something happen and handle all the async events in the main GUI thread

```
namespace net = boost::asio;
int main()
{
    net::io_context ioContext;
    AsyncClass myClass(ioContext);

    // gui code
    myClass.onAsyncEvent1([] { /* update gui */ });
    myClass.onAsyncEvent2([] { /* update gui */ });

    thread asyncThread{[&ioContext] {
        ioContext.wait();
        // this is blocking until the message is done
        sendMessageToGUI(GUI_CUSTOM_EVENT);
    }

    while(true)
    {
        GUIEvent event;
        // this is blocking
        GetMessage(event);

        if (event == GUI_CUSTOM_EVENT)
            ioContext.run_one();  // run_one or poll_one are the same here
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately Boost.Asio doesn't provide such utility...

**QUESTIONS**

1. Why such functionality is not implemented in Boost? Or maybe Boost.Asio is just not the right tool for async code in GUI applications
2. Is this method wrong? Maybe are smarter way to do this.

**POSSIBLE SOLUTION?**

A possible solution could just call the `sendMessageToGUI` from the callback...

```
namespace net = boost::asio;
int main()
{
 net::io_context ioContext, guiContext;
 AsyncClass myClass(ioContext);

 // non gui code
 myClass.onAsyncEvent1([] { /* do stuff */ });
 myClass.onAsyncEvent2([] { /* do stuff */ });
 myClass.onAsyncEvent3([] { /* do stuff */ });
 myClass.onAsyncEvent4([] { /* do stuff */ });

 // gui code
 myClass.onAsyncEvent1([&guiContext]
 {
   postGUIMessage(GUI_CUSTOM_MESSAGE);
   guiContext.post([]{
     // this will unlock the main thread
     ui->laber->setText("yes!");
   }
 });

 myClass.onAsyncEvent4([&guiContext]
 {
   postGUIMessage(GUI_CUSTOM_MESSAGE);
   guiContext.post([]{
     // this will unlock the main thread
     ui->laber->setText("yes!");
   }
 });

 thread_pool.enqueue{[&ioContext] { ioContext.run(); }

 while(true)
 {
   GUIEvent event;
   // this is blocking
   GetMessage(event);

   if (event == GUI_CUSTOM_EVENT)    
     guiContext.poll();  

   return 0;
}
```

The benefit is that I can handle benefit from multi-core and redirect only GUI events...

Comment: Can you expand on why `poll`ing the context doesn't work?

Comment: poll of course will work... I just don't wanna waste time in polling when I can block the main thread. This means lower cpu usage and higher battery duration

Comment: Where did you want to block that you can't block? I'm having trouble spotting it in the second example. Is it the `wait` call (which `io_context` doesn't actually have)?

Comment: Well if you block the main thread for GUI events you cannot handle async events... if you call `run` you block the main thread and you cannot handle GUI events

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you're trying to use Asio along with a totally different async API with its own blocking wait, and on the same thread. I don't think this is possible, because Asio requires you donate a thread entirely to it. In general I don't know of any library that allows you to mix like this without polling. I think short of using something like co-routines or fibers, you need to have each thread dedicated to a single async API.

Comment: The usual(?) way to achieve this is to have the GUI use the 'main' thread and have boost.asio functionality on its own thread.  The asio thread can post events to the GUI thread and you can use a socket pair (or pipe or similar) to notify the asio code from the GUI.

Comment: @G.M. notify asio code from GUI is easy... I can call the `post` method of the `io_context` no need to pipe or socketes... Do you think my possible solution can work?

Comment: I think so.  Sorry, I misread your proposed solution initially.  It looks like we're both thinking along the same lines with the one exception that you're using `boost::asio::post` rather the any pipe etc.

Comment: I will try that solution then... let's see if it works :D

Comment: @elvis.dukaj Be care that in Windows world [SendMessage does not return until the window procedure has processed the message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendmessage)